# MS Dos Schedule Scripting

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I would like to ask for your assistance as I'm a beginner in scripting. I want to perform a script with the following conditions.

- every 1st Saturday of the month I need to run echo Monthly
- every Saturday of the month I need to run echo Weekly
- the rest of the day I need to run echo Daily

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works; you need to attempt something, and if you get stuck, come back with your code, what doesn't work, and what errors you are getting.  Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: right. But as a starting point: `schtasks /create /?` fulfilles all your requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task Scheduler in three schedules, and in your batch file you can detect the weekday and date and abort if it is not one of the desired days of the week, also checking if it has run already that day - if that is needed.